# Create a filter in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is my issue, I am working on wordpress, using datafeedr woocommerce importer to import my products from datafeedr to woocomemerce. When I add a new product set, I get information about brand but in the woocommerce products the brand is not display. Is there any way I can import the brands and create a filter for my products by brand? Also I want to create a filter by merchants.

Comment: I would try contacting the creator of the plug-in.

Comment: Thanks Raphael,just want you know that I am new in usa,I moved few months ago,I am learning English, Actually I speak French,that way I make a mistakes,I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a brand attribute to your products and then pull the brand into that attribute, e.g.

```
<?php
/* Add Brand attribute to the product */
add_filter( 'dfrpswc_product_attributes', 'mycode_add_brand_attribute', 20, 5 );
function mycode_add_brand_attribute( $attributes, $post, $product, $set, $action ) {
    if ( isset( $product['brand'] ) ) {
        $attr = 'Brand';
        if ( !isset( $attributes[sanitize_title( $attr )] ) ) {
            $attributes[$attr]['name'] = $attr;
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}

/**
 * Set value for "Brand" attribute.
 */
add_filter( 'dfrpswc_filter_attribute_value', 'mycode_set_brand_attribute_value', 30, 6 );
function mycode_set_brand_attribute_value( $value, $attribute, $post, $product, $set, $action ) {
    if ( isset( $product['brand'] ) ) {
        $attr = 'Brand';
        if ( $attribute == $attr ) {
            $value = $product['brand'];
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```